# Ansible - How to optimize sending a file to a sub-network?

Tags: 20.04, ansible

I have a playbook that looks:

```
- name: Playbook para Copiar JRE
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Copia Arquivo JRE
      copy:
        src: jre.tar.gz
        dest: /home/pdv/sistema-loja/jre-new.tar.gz
```

And hosts:

```
[13]
0013-03.filial.local
0013-04.filial.local
0013-05.filial.local
0013-06.filial.local
0013-07.filial.local
0013-08.filial.local
0013-09.filial.local
0013-16.filial.local
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbook copia-jre.yml -u pdv --ask-pass
```

The group [13] is a remote network with limited bandwidth, so I want to optimize it by sending the file one time to the sub-network and reuse it.

I could choose ONE machine and then distribute.

Is it possible? how?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: All machines are Ubuntu 20.04, local and remote. ansible 2.9.6